# Projective complex space is Hausdorff

Tags: linear-algebra, general-topology, matrices

I'm trying to understand the proof that the complex Projective space is Hausdorff. The proof states that this is equivalent by a earlier result to the fact that the set:
$$ K = \{(x,y)\in (\mathbb C^{n+1}-\{0\})^2 \mid x = \lambda y\}$$
is closed in $(\mathbb C^{n+1}-\{0\})^2$. Now my prof just claimed that this is obvious because we can identify $K$ as matrices and this matrices and the $\det$ map is continuous.

But I dont understand the last part. What is the meaning of 'identifying' and what role does the $\det$ map play?

Comment: What (I think) your professor wants doesn't work if $\lambda$ may be any complex number. It works if $\lambda$ is restricted to $\Bbb R$

Comment: @FShrike What are you talking about?!

Comment: Do you know about the exterior (wedge) product of vectors? If so, you have a continuous (bilinear) map $\wedge\colon V\times V \to \Lambda^2 V$ and $v,w$ are linearly dependent iff $v\wedge w = 0$.

Comment: @TedShifrin I was thinking about the case $n=0$ in particular and I mistakenly thought we wanted to identify $\Bbb C^2\cong\Bbb R^{2\times 2}$ and the matrix: $$\begin{pmatrix}\Re x&\Re y\\\Im x&\Im y\end{pmatrix}$$Can have nonzero determinant still if there is a complex. non-real, $\lambda$ with $x=\lambda y$. I was on the wrong track

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what your professor means is that you can identify K with $2 \times n+1$, so in the first column there are component of $x$ and in the second the component of $y$. Then if this matrix has rank 1 the the vector are proportional and your matrix is in $K$. Now to verify if your matrix has rank one you just compute the determinant of all $2\times 2$ minors. Therefore $K$ is the $0$ preimage of some continuous map and therefore closed.

Comment: why is a 2*(n+1) matrix of rank 1 iff all 2*2 minors have determinant 0?

Comment: It is a standard fact in linear algebra, but if you think a moment is just if a minor has 0 determinant, its columns are linearly dependent. So to check if two columns are linearly dependent you just check a $2 \times 2$ piece at a time.

Comment: oh yes thank you!